# How old is Charles Muntz during "Up"?

Tags: character, up

In *Up*, Charles Muntz is the main villain. At the beginning of the movie, he is shown when Carl and Ellie are young - he's an adult already. Fast forward to when *Up* takes place. Ellie has passed away, Carl is in his seventies, and Charles... doesn't actually look that much older. He looked about the same - or even more spry - as Carl.

Do we have any idea how old he was at any time?

Comment: As an aside regarding the spryness: Charles spent every day hunting an elusive creature in the wilderness while Frederick spent most of his time in a rocking chair. Staying active is important.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

According to [Disney Wikia](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Charles_F._Muntz#Trivia):

> Considering that Muntz is in his early 20's and Carl is 9 at the beginning of the movie, and that Carl is 78 by the time he takes off with his house, Muntz could be over 90 years old when they meet.

And there is a link to a [tweet from Lee Unkrich](https://twitter.com/leeunkrich/status/2304049837) (director of Coco and Toy Story 3) in which it states:

> At the beginning of the movie, Carl is 9, Muntz is 23. Per Pete.

(Pete being Pete Docter, co-director of Up) If at the beginning of the movie, Muntz is 23, and it has been 69 years. Then **Charles Muntz is 92** when he meets Carl.